# Porting a pre-populated sqlite database in Ionic

Tags: android, angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor

**Technologies used for the app:** `Ionic`, `Capacitor`, `Angular` and `SQLite`

The requirement is to use a prepopulated `SQLite` database in the app. The methods that I found over the internet across various blogs and forums mentioned running a `SQL script` to initialize the DB as a pre-population step, but this brings about an unwanted overhead time to start querying the DB. As in the user needs to wait for a minute or so for the SQL Script to run completely every time, even if the app exists.

This issue became a roadblock because when the need became to port a large-sized database, it was no longer feasible to write SQL scripts as the overhead time increased drastically. Also, a bigger problem is, in `Android studio`, `Java` started throwing `Heap Memory exceeded error`.

A solution that I tried was to port the database directly as an asset of the app so that it can be shipped along with the app. But, while placing the database file in `src/assets/`, every build of the app generates `www/` to create a web app that can be wrapped in a native view. The builder and compiler delete all the contents of the previous build in the `www/` folder, we must understand that the capacitor looks for the database file at `www/` and not in `www/assets/`, but we can't place the database file at `www/` as it gets deleted on every build.

Link to existing issue on using the [sqlite extension](https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-ext/issues/89)

Comment: did you look into using the capacitor sqlite plugin? Also you should only take the hit of populating the database when the application is first installed

Answer (score 0):

maybe my experience can help you

RULES FOR DEVELOPMENT

1
database1 of bundle ( Android APK) from /assets must be static and not for update. because they can be changed when the application will be reinstalled on you version

2
you must to create new database2 - local , on the device , programmatically - to store a user's data. you can affill this database2 with data from database1

3
when you will install new version of application: database1 one may be changed, but the database2 becomes constant

the same situation is in browser: programmatically created database not disappear from session to session.

I check - it works in my application...